# Elasticsearch: Filtering/matching multiple phrases

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my JSON which I am searching ....

```
{ courseintakes: "Trimester 1; Trimester 2; Trimester 3" }
{ courseintakes: "Trimester 1; Trimester 2" }
{ courseintakes: "Trimester 2; Trimester 3" }
{ courseintakes: "Trimester 1"}
{ courseintakes: "Trimester 3"}
```

I have also setup a custom analyser and applied to this field which breaks this field on a semi-colon (;)...

```
"analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "semi_colon_analyzer": {
               "type": "pattern",
               "pattern": ";"
            }
         }
      }
```

Now, what is the best way to efficiently search this field ...

**I tried this (no results returned)**

```
"must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "courseintakes": [
              "Trimester 2",
              "Trimester 3"
            ]
          }
        }
```

**Then, I tried this (no results returned)**

```
"match": {
            "courseintakes": "Trimester 2,Trimester 3"
          }
```

What am I doing wrong ? How should I efficiently search this ?

**Example scenario**: What I am expecting is that when I search on say *Trimester 1 & Trimester 2*, it should return all the rows/records that have either/any of these Trimesters listed.

**Here is the mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "courses": {
      "properties": {
        "courseintakes": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "course_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anything is not clear, please feel free to ask.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide you'r `mapping`. The problem could be the array type you are using. And also he output for : `GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "semi_colon_analyzer",
  "text" : "Trimester 1; Trimester 2; Trimester 3"
}`

Comment: @MohammadMazraeh I have added  mapping as  you requested. I removed  the analyser, because I was not getting the desired results.

Comment: @Slyper: Which version Of ES are you using?

Comment: @Richa I am using version 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change your custom analyzer. You can see how your text is getting analyzed as per current analyzer using [Analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

```
   POST custom/_analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer
   {
    "text" :  "Trimester 1; Trimester 3"
   }
```

You will get following output:

```
 {
  "tokens": [
   {
     "token": " trimester 1",       <==== Please note a space in beginning
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 11,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
   },
   {
     "token": " trimester 3",           <==== Please note a space in beginning
     "start_offset": 13,
     "end_offset": 24,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 1
    }
  ]
 }
```

Change your analyzer to :

```
 "analyzer": {
        "semi_colon_analyzer": {
           "type": "pattern",
           "pattern": "; ",     <== Space after semi colon
           "lowercase" : false
        }
     }
```

You text will tokenized in following form:

```
  {
    "tokens": [
     {
      "token": "Trimester 1",       <==== No space in beginning
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": " trimester 3",           <==== No space in beginning
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 24,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
     }
   ]
  }
```

Then apply `terms` query and it will work

```
    {
      "terms": {
        "courseintakes": [
          "Trimester 2",
          "Trimester 3"
        ]
      }
    }
```

hope it helps!!

Comment: Hi Richa, Thanks for your reply.  I changed the pattern as you specified .... Now when run this `_analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer&text='Trimester 1; Trimester 2; Trimester 3'` I get this error 

`{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "request [/all_test/_analyze] contains unrecognized parameters: [ Trimester 2], [ Trimester 3']"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}`

Comment: Just give it a try using: `POST index_name/_analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer
{"text":"Trimester 1; Trimester 3"}`

Comment: Not much change, I get this now ..... `{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "request [/all_test/_analyze] contains unrecognized parameter: [ Trimester 3\"}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "request [/all_test/_analyze] contains unrecognized parameter: [ Trimester 3\"}]"
  },
  "status": 400
}`

Comment: It works if you just use a single trimester like `_analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer&text=Trimester 1;` As soon as you add anything else, it breaks

Comment: That's strange.. I am running this `POST index_name/_analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer {"text":"Trimester 1; Trimester 3"}` and it is working perfectly fine

Comment: Try as per given in documentation  `GET indexName/_analyze
{
   "analyzer": "semi_colon_analyzer",
   "text": "Trimester 1; Trimester 2; Trimester 3"
}
`

Comment: ok, Its working now Richa. But there is another problem .... When I use this command   `{
      "terms": {
        "courseintakes": [
          "Trimester 2",
          "Trimester 3"
        ]
      }
    }` I get this .....   `{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Unknown parameter [terms] in request body or parameter is of the wrong type[START_OBJECT] "
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145332/discussion-between-richa-and-slyper).