# How to search/filter for exact multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my JSON ....

```
[{
    "course_id": 1,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 1; Trimester 2; Trimester 3"
}, {
    "course_id": 2,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 1; Trimester 2"
}, {
    "course_id": 3,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 2; Trimester 3"
}, {
    "course_id": 4,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 1; Trimester 3"
}, {
    "course_id": 5,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 3"
}]
```

What I am trying to do is that when someone search on *Trimester 1 or Trimester 2*, it should  return course with id 1, 2, 3 and 4 but not 5.

If someone search on *Trimester 1 or Trimester 3*, it should  return course with id 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

I have tried `terms query` and `match query`.

`terms query` doesn't return any results.
`match query` return results, but its not precise enough.

Can someone please advise what's the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the mapping and ES version

Comment: All sorted now ... Found the complete solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227658/elasticsearch-pattern-analyser-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your elastic query
ideally it should be

```
{
    "size": <size>,
    "_source": <fields to retrieve>,
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "courseintakes": [<query_terms>, <query_terms>]
        }
    }
}
```

use _source to filter out returned fields. 
also check what mapping you have. ideally you should have non analyzed fields for courseintakes and if you want analyzed fields then consider creating your own analyzers for the field courseintakes that splits the word on basis of ";"

Comment: @KuldeepKRishi I did the custom analyser, please see this similar question I asked a couple of days ago  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149335/elasticsearch-filtering-matching-multiple-phrases