# Elasticsearch: Pattern analyser not working

Tags: elasticsearch

**Here is my mapping with a pattern analyser specified ...**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": "0",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "semi_colon_analyzer": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ";"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "courseintakes": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "semi_colon_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "semi_colon_analyzer"
        },
        "course_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is the sample data I want to index ...**

```
{
    "course_id": 1,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 1; Trimester 2; Trimester 3"
}, {
    "course_id": 2,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 1; Trimester 2"
}, {
    "course_id": 3,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 2; Trimester 3"
}, {
    "course_id": 4,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 1; Trimester 3"
}, {
    "course_id": 5,
    "courseintakes": "Trimester 3"
}
```

**For some  reason, my pattern analyser is not working** .... When I test the analyser i.e. http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9200/all_test/_analyze?filter=semi_colon_analyzer&text='Trimester 1'

I get this .... (*instead of "token": "trimester 1"*)

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "trimester",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "1",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I am trying to do** is that when someone search on Trimester 1 or Trimester 2, it should return course with id 1, 2, 3 and 4 **but not 5**.

If someone search on Trimester 1 or Trimester 3, it should return course with id 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 i.e. all courses.

What is the best way to achieve  this ?

I have  tried my best to explain this but if anything is still unclear, please feel free to ask.

Any help from an ES expert is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `analyzer` to following one:

```
 "analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "semi_colon_analyzer": {
      "type": "pattern",
      "pattern": "; "        <=== Note this space
    }
  }
}
```

Also you are running wrong query to test your analyzer. You are using `filter`, instead you need to use `analyzer` key.Correct query is

```
/_analyze?analyzer=semi_colon_analyzer&text=Trimester 1; Trimester 3
```

Hope this helps!!